# Spring Cloud Stream > SendTo does not send to Kafka but directly via direct channel

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have two channels in my application which hare bound to two Kafka topics:

1. input
2. error.input.my-group

Input is configured in order to send message to dlq (error.input.my-group) in case of error.

I have a StreamListener on "error.input.my-group" which is configured in order to send the message back to original channel.

```
@StreamListener(Channels.DLQ)
@SendTo(Channels.INPUT)
public Message<?> reRoute(Message<?> failed){
    messageDeliveryService.waitUntilCanBeDelivered(failed);
    processed.incrementAndGet();
    Integer retries = failed.getHeaders().get(X_RETRIES_HEADER, Integer.class);
    retries = retries == null ? 1 : retries+1;
     if (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
        logger.info("Retry (count={}) for {}", retries, failed);
        return buildRetryMessage(failed, retries);
    }
    else {
        logger.error("Retries exhausted (-> sent to parking lot) for {}", failed);
        Channels.parkingLot().send(MessageBuilder.fromMessage(failed)
                .setHeader(BinderHeaders.PARTITION_OVERRIDE,
                        failed.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID))
                .build());
    }
    return null;
}

private Message<?> buildRetryMessage(Message<?> failed, int retries) {
    return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(failed)
            .setHeader(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retries)
            .setHeader(BinderHeaders.PARTITION_OVERRIDE,
                    failed.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID))
            .build();
}
```

Here is my Channels class

```
        @Component
    public interface Channels {

        String INPUT = "INPUT";
        //Default name use by SCS (error.<input-topic-name>.<group-name>)
        String DLQ = "error.input.my-group";
        String PARKING_LOT = "parkingLot.input.my-group";

        @Input(INPUT)
        SubscribableChannel input();

        @Input(DLQ)
        SubscribableChannel dlq();

        @Output(PARKING_LOT)
        MessageChannel parkingLot();


}
```

Here is my configuration

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        group: my-group
      binder:
        headerMode: headers      kafka:
        binder:
          # Necessary in order to commit the message to all the Kafka brokers handling the partition -> maximum durability
          # -1 = all
          requiredAcks: -1
          brokers: bootstrap.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,bootstrap.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9093,bootstrap.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9094,bootstrap.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9095,bootstrap.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9096,bootstrap.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9097
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              partitioned: true
              enableDlq: true
              dlqProducerProperties:
                configuration:
                  key.serializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
          "[error.input.my-group]":
            consumer:
              # We cannot loose any message and we don't have any DLQ for the DLQ, therefore we only commit in case of success
              autoCommitOnError: false
              ackEachRecord: true
              partitioned: true
              enableDlq: false
      bindings:
        input:
          contentType: application/xml
          destination: input
        "[error.input.my-group]":
          contentType: application/xml
          destination: error.input.my-group
        "[parkingLot.input.my-group]":
          contentType: application/xml
          destination: parkingLot.input.my-group
```

Problem is my messages are never pushed again to Kafka but directly delivered to my input channel. Is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The Messages are sent to the output channel (INPUT in your case), but then the binder sends it out to the topic. 
While most certainly you have missconfigured something, there is not enough information in your question for us to figure out what it is. Could you please post your project on GitHib or some other place so we can take a look?

Comment: Like Oleg, I misunderstood your question; I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `@SendTo` the kafka destination instead of directly, you need an output binding.

Comment: I just followed the followed the pattern proposed in Spring Cloud Stream documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-dlq-processing). Except that instead of having a separated JVM I run the dead letter queue consumption in the same JVM. Why do I need a separate input binding to consume from that topic?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question; Oleg was right. In order for the `@SendTo` to go to Kafka, you need an OUTPUT destination, not send directly to the input channel.

Comment: I just updated my question in order to provide more details. What I don't understand is that I have followed the documentation which seems to indicate that the messages will be republished to the Kafka topic using the @SendTo.

Comment: I think I understood. I need to define this:
    @Output("input")
    SubscribableChannel input();
    @Output("input")
    MessageChannel output();

Is it enough or must I use a different channel?

Comment: It needs to be a different channel, and you will need to add the output binding to the YML too. In the documentation, the `@SendTo` refers to an OUTPUT binding; you are directly wiring it to your main INPUT channel.